# Google sheets, repeated text

Tags: google-sheets

I'm creating a google sheet document for organising a tournament. 
I'll leave here the sheet so you can see https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ov0Zme0jgLEnvuV1tFH577iNe1TzwmPgf6iOuECPdmc/edit?usp=sharing

I would like to have another table with two columns. 
Team name | Number of apparitions

That way I can see if a team is complete or not. The team name column is the column called Equipo.
Anyone can help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already did it on two steps.

1. I used =UNIQUE(F:F) on H column (F is the column with the team names) for the Team Name column
2. I used =COUNTIF(F:F; H14) where H14 is the team name to search (obtained on the previous step) for the number of apparition of that name in F column